# iOS app launch time and secondary thread

Tags: ios, launch, instrumentation

I am using time profiler to analyse my app launch time.
Does secondary/background thread also impact app launch time.

Please clarify secondary thread role at app launch time.

If we are comparing launch time for two versions of app, Should we consider time differences in secondary threads as well.
What should be the best approach?

Thanks

Comment: If you app can start a second thread then by definition it's already launched. No?

Answer (score 0):

App is launched after you return true from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions. Background thread won't block launching if it was async.

Comment: Yes, But threads which are created and we can see in time profiler will not impact app launch?For example time profiler showing up secondary threads as well when we stop app after its become interactive to user.Or if I filter time profiler result by time to launch sign (using time profiler purple indicator). Then also its shows some secondary threads as well and launch time is sum of main and all secondary threads created till that time.

Comment: @rtk123 Background thread has much lower priority on processor time than main thread. So the impact is not so perceptible. But you are right it impacts launch time - there is no magic ))